# Why can't I connect to postgres from Perl?

Tags: perl, postgresql, tcp, dbi

I believe i have set up Pg properly, but my script doesn't seem to be connecting to the database. I am testing with:

```
$database="networkem";
$user="postgres";
$password="";
$host="localhost";

$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$host", $user, $password);
```

My pg_hba reads:

```
host  all  postgres   127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   trust
```

I can use `psql` just fine via command-line and have started postmaster with -i option. What am I missing?

I also tried with another user that works fine via psql:

```
$user="jimbo"; $password="p2ssw0rd";
```

with pg_hba reading:

```
host    all    jimbo   127.0.0.1    255.255.255.255    trust
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Answer (score 11):

Rather than play 20 questions to debug your setup, `DBI->errstr` will say why the connection failed.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(...) or die DBI->errstr;
```

Though if I had to guess... since Postgres authenticates based on host and login user, I suspect the confusion lies between the user name you're giving to the Postgres connection and the Unix user you're logged in as.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Schwern's excellent response, you can also check PostgreSQL log which, depending on the options selected in postgresql.conf may tell you a lot about what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you use the 'listen_addresses' configuration option in your postgresql.conf instead of '-i' on the command line. For example:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Try executing the following command as the same user you are running your perl script with:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost networkem
```

The '-h localhost' forces a network connection instead of a Unix socket connection.  If that command works, your perl script should also work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The hint above for trying "-h localhost" confirmed that I had a problem connecting over the network.

Adding the following to pg_hba.conf fixed the problem.

```
host all postgres 127.0.0.1/32 trust
```

Answer (score 0):

DBI may be connecting to either the IPv4 or IPv6 postgresql server interface, depending on how things are configured.

So you may need both of these lines in pg_hba.conf:

IPv4:

```
host  all  <user>  127.0.0.1/32  trust
```

IPv6:

```
host  all  <user>  ::1/128       trust
```